# No module named keras on floydhub

Tags: keras, gpu

I uploaded my dataset on floydhub. while running the python script with keras env, i'm getting an error "No module named keras"

[Here's the screenshot of the error page from floydhub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF1iy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'keras' environment on FloydHub.
You should use
    `--env tensorflow-1.11:py2`
Full list of valid environment names is [here](https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/environments/).